# Ring motion in an hemispherical bottle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, moment-of-inertia

Suppose we add a ring of radius $ r $ and mass $ m $ into an hemispherical bottle of radius $ R $, how can we find the differential equation for it in terms of the angle $ \theta $ made from vertical and $ \alpha $ is the angle that ring rotated. I tried to solve with energy conservation:

$ E = K_{rot_\theta} + K_{rot_\alpha} + U_{pot} $

$ E = \frac{I_\theta \dot{\theta}^2}{2} + \frac{I_\alpha \dot{\alpha}^2}{2}+mg(R-r)(1-\cos(\theta)) $

Where $ I_\theta $ is the moment of inertia of the ring relative to $ \theta $ and $ I_\alpha $ the moment of inertia of the ring relatively to it's center of mass. Solving it and considering that $ r \dot{\alpha} = - R \dot{\theta} $ and that $ I_\theta = m(r^2+(R-r)^2), I_\alpha = m r^2 $ I got:

$ \ddot{\theta}+\frac{g (R-r)}{(R-r)^2+R^2+r^2}\sin(\theta)=0 $

I would like to ask if considering the kinetic energy of the ring around $ \theta $ as $ \frac{I_\theta \dot{\theta}^2}{2} $ is correct, rather than considering it as translational $ \frac{m v^2}{2} $.

[image]

Comment: That's my first question in this site, and it's Portuguese. I'm still learning how to use latex. I just want to know if I should consider rotation kinetics energy rather than translational

Comment: The edit has made this a much better question!

Comment: Thank you! I was searching about how to use latex while editing (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful about how you define the moment of inertia $I_\theta$: if you consider the rotation of the ring separately (which you do with your relationship between $\alpha$ and $\theta$), then I think the inertia about $\theta$ would just be $m(R-r)^2$. The value you came up with would be correct if you attached the ring to a rigid massless rod - because then you get some additional inertia from the fact that you force the ring to rotate when the rod changes angle. But here it is probably easier (and OK) to think of the translation and rotation separately.

Comment: But if I consider that the ring doesn't slide, then $ I_\theta $ could be $ m(R-r)^2 + mr^2 $? (That's the moment given by the parallel axis theorem).

Comment: You need to use the moment of inertia corresponding to the motion. The value you quote would be the right value if you consider the motion to be rotation of the entire ring with angular velocity $\dot\theta$. But that's not the motion of the ring... so you can't use that. Instead you need to compute the contribution of translation and rotation separately (the parallel axis theorem does that for you in the special case when the angular velocity of the c.o.m. is the same as the angular velocity about the c.o.m.). Do you see it now?

Comment: Great! I understand now, thank you! Since the moment of inertia should be $ I_\theta = m(R-r)^2 $, then the differential equation is quite equal, but without the $ r^2 $. I was confusing these concepts of moment of inertia and now I understand. Thank you again.